# How to Update Toggle button based on Checkbox in LWC

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

Want to update checkbox based on toggle option in LWC Salesforce.

```
<lightning-input type="checkbox" label=" " name="Active" onclick={handleChange}></lightning-input>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? and can you define what toggle option means?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? It'll help if you [edit] your question to include more details and the code that you've written so far.

Comment: <lightning-input type="checkbox" label=" " name="Active" value={selectedStatus} onclick={handleChange}></lightning-input>

Comment: want js code to fetch actions and save in salesforce database

Comment: Added code but you should go through LWC documentation.It has the information you are looking for

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check this [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_conditional) link in LWC which has example of what you are asking for

```
<!-- helloConditionalRendering.html -->
<template>
    <lightning-card title="HelloConditionalRendering" icon-name="custom:custom14">
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
            <lightning-input type="checkbox" label="Show details" onchange={handleChange}></lightning-input>
            <template if:true={areDetailsVisible}>
                <div class="slds-m-vertical_medium">
                    These are the details!
                </div>
            </template>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Code to toggle is in the below js file

```
// helloConditionalRendering.js
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

export default class HelloConditionalRendering extends LightningElement {
    @track areDetailsVisible = false;

    handleChange(event) {
        this.areDetailsVisible = event.target.checked;
    }
}
```